# An open cover for $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ that does not contain a finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

$\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ is not compact since any irrational number $\in [0,1]$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ but $\notin\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.

Then, there must exist a open cover for $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ that does not have a finite subcover.

So, i'm thinking of constructing a sequence of open intervals.

Let $O_n = (-1,\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} - \frac{1}{2n})$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$,

where $(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} - \frac{1}{2n}) \rightarrow \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$

I claim that $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}O_n \cup (\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},2) \supseteq [0,1]$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$

Case 1: $x \in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,\frac{\sqrt 2}{2})$.

$\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} - x > 0 \implies 2(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} -x) >0$

By Archimedean Property, $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < 2(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} -x)$ $\implies \frac{1}{2n} < \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} -x$ $\implies \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} - \frac{1}{2n} > x$ $\implies x\in (-1,\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} -\frac{1}{2n})$

Case 2: $x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap (\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},1]$

Then, $x\in (\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},2)$

Hence, $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}O_n \cup (\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},2) \supseteq [0,1]$ and $\big \{(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}, 2), O_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\big \}$ is an open cover for $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.

Now, i want to show that the open cover for $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ does not have a finite subcover.

Suppose on the contrary that $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ has a finite subcover.

Then, the finite subcover has the form $\{(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},2), O_{n_{1}}, O_{n_{2}}, ... ,O_{n_{k}}$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N} \big \}$.

Let $M=$ max$\big \{{n_{1}},{n_{2}},...,{n_{k}}\big \}$

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{N}$, $\exists y\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}-\frac{1}{2M}<y<\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$

But the finite subcover does not contain $y$, which is a contradiction.

I'll be glad if someone can check if my proof is alright. Thanks.

Comment: The finite subcover $\{(-1, \sqrt2 - \frac{1}{2000})\}$ covers all of your space.

Comment: Why do you choose the number $\sqrt{2}$? I suspect you want to choose some irrational in $[0,1]$ for the task.

Comment: Oh no, i wanted to choose $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$, let me edit my post

Comment: @Arthur How's my proof now?

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper How's my proof now?

Comment: The idea is good. However, your definition of $M$ could use a little work. The way it is now, if you use the finite subcover $\{(\sqrt2/2,2),(-1,\sqrt2/2-1/2000)\}$, then $M=1000$, and $M<y<\sqrt2/2$ is not possible. There are a few other, similar formalia that are lacking and need to be fixed for the proof to be considered correct and complete, like saying that $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}O_n \cup (\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},2) \supseteq [0,1]$, when the left side clearly doesn't contain $\sqrt2/2$.

Comment: @Arthur sorry i meant $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}-\frac{1}{2M}<y<\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$

Answer (score 6):

Your idea is fine.

It's simpler if you take
$$
O_n=
\left(-\infty,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)
\cup
\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\infty\right)
$$
Prove that $\{O_n:n\ge1\}$ is a cover of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$.

However
$$
O_1\subset O_2\subset\dots\subset O_n\subset\dotsb
$$
and so a finite subcover would be just one $O_n$. But there is a rational number $q$ with
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{n}<q<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
$$
so $q\notin O_n$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Note that, when n=1, $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{n}<0$. Therefore, the $q$ you find might not even be in [0, 1]. I think it might be necessary to change the left side of the inequality to something like $\max{\{0, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\}}$.

Comment: @Wiza The $n$ we'd find cannot be $1$, because $O_1$ is not a cover.

Comment: @egreg I see, but $O_n$ in general is not a cover, right? In other words, no matter what $n$ is, we don't have a cover, and finding $q\in[0,1]$ but $q\notin O_n$ is how we justified that. Because of this we do need to consider $n=1$?

Comment: @Wiza If you prefer, you can treat $O_1$ on its own.